# Is it fine to store i18n data in the database?

Tags: database, firebase, internationalization

I'm building a multilingual web application and I'm struggling to decide, how to store i18n data.

On the one hand, I could go with a traditional way of saving phrases into a JSON file and loading it from there. But for my application I'm using *create-react-app* and *firebase*, which makes this pretty inconvenient (It's fine to load phrases, but I would also like my i18n library to save missing translations into files, which is not so easy, because I have to setup a small *express* server which would handle file modifications).

On the other hand, I could just store everything in the database. That would make this process much simpler, but is it fine to do it? Are there any pitfalls or maybe security issues? (I know no one probably cares about stealing translated text, but if it's changed somehow, that wouldn't be nice for the users)

Comment: If someone has access to your data then your translations are the least of your worries

Answer (score 1):

I prefer to use JSON format. In the cases of you can't upload a ".json" file you can use a ".js" file without inconvenient. For example:

**en.js**

```js
module.exports = {
    "sayHi": "hello",
};
```

**es.js**

```js
module.exports = {
    "sayHi": "hola",
};
```

If you don't want to miss any translation text of any language you can create a little script who alerts you if there is a missing text. In another hand, you can create another script to fill the incomplete languages and generate new .js files.